# Flash CS6 larger icon sizes for Android publishing (AIR 4.0)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs6

When publishing for Android, Flash CS6 only shows icon options for 32x32, 48x48, and 72x72 icons. However, I wish to also have 96x96 and 144x144 icons. When I edit the -app.xml file to include these, publishing the project overwrites the file to have only have the 32x32, 48x48, and 72x72 icons. Is there any way to publish the project with larger icon sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Set your publish setting.
2. Add icons using include files in publish settings.
3. Manuallay edit your manifest file to add icons.
4. Change the XML descriptor properties to read only.
5. Publish the app.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update your AIR sdk. Since 3.8 it should support those sizes out of the box, the newest release even more.